# BottomSheetBehavior Illegal state argument: 5

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, bottom-sheet

Could someone explain about when this exception occurs?

```
12-18 11:20:07.225 15944-15944/com.test.dev.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dev.debug, PID: 15944
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal state argument: 5
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.startSettlingAnimation(BottomSheetBehavior.java:631)
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior$1.run(BottomSheetBehavior.java:550)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Java class

```
public class BottomSheetController {

    private BottomSheetBehavior<View> bottomSheetBehavior;
    private WeakReference<FrameLayout> bottomSheetContainer;
    private Slide slide;

    public interface Slide {
        void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset);
    }

    public void bind(FrameLayout bottomSheetContainer) {
        this.bottomSheetContainer = new WeakReference<>(bottomSheetContainer);
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(this.bottomSheetContainer.get());
        bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(sheetCallback());
    }

    public void unbind() {
        this.bottomSheetContainer.clear();
    }

    public void setSlide(Slide slide) {
        this.slide = slide;
    }

    public void collapse() {
        bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    }

    public void expand() {
        bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }

    public void hide() {
        bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    }

    public int getState() {
        return bottomSheetBehavior.getState();
    }

    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback sheetCallback() {
        return new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

                if (newState != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
                } else {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

                if (slide != null) {
                    slide.onSlide(bottomSheet, slideOffset);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
public class IllegalArgumentException extends RuntimeException
```

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or
>   inappropriate argument.

Somewhere in your code, you are passing an illegal argument to the method `startSettlingAnimation()` (`BottomSheetBehavior` class). This method is throwing the exception:

```
void startSettlingAnimation(View child, int state) {
    int top;
    if (state == STATE_COLLAPSED) {
      top = mCollapsedOffset;
    } else if (state == STATE_HALF_EXPANDED) {
      top = mHalfExpandedOffset;
    } else if (state == STATE_EXPANDED) {
      top = getExpandedOffset();
    } else if (mHideable && state == STATE_HIDDEN) {
      top = mParentHeight;
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal state argument: " + state);
    }
    if (mViewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(child, child.getLeft(), top)) {
      setStateInternal(STATE_SETTLING);
      ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(child, new SettleRunnable(child, state));
    } else {
      setStateInternal(state);
    }
  }
```

Your error is: `Illegal state argument: 5`. 5 is the int value of `STATE_HIDDEN`. So while your state is `STATE_HIDDEN` (5), your `mHideable` boolean is false. So, the basic suggestion would be to **set the mHideable = true**;

Without any code, that's as much as I can tell you.

Comment: Make sense, I've added my controller class.

Comment: I think the problem is that the `bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);` part is not being called at some conditions inside your `bind()` method, since it also might not be called for some reason. Try debugging your app with break points.

Comment: The test team are running monkey test, it make hard to debug. But i believe that problem is here :

`public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState)`

Comment: I think the accepted answer should be @SerjArdovic 's comment  the `bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);` needs to be called.

Answer (score 11):

For me problem was resolved by `sheetBehavior.setHideable(true);`
It seems when `setHideable` is false and then setting state to `BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN` exception will occurred

Answer (score 2):

As @Serj Ardovic explain it s the Hideable

I wanted to add that you can also put it in the xml :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:behavior_hideable="true"   <- this here
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
```